# Plot all the colums of matrix vs first column of matrix with plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I am having a 2d matrix which i wish to plot column wise against a first column,I am able to plot it using matplot, is there any way to do a similar thing using plotly, I tried using by adding them as traces but it was overwriting the traces not adding them.

```
mat <- array(rnorm(10*10*10), dim=c(10, 10, 10))
df <- data.frame( 500*(1:10))
for(i in 3:5){
  for(j in 4:5){
    df <-  cbind(df,mat[1:10,i,j])
  }
}
matplot(x= df[,1], y= as.matrix(df[-1]), type='l')
# plot_ly(y= as.matrix(df[-1]), x= df[,1] ,type="scatter", mode="markers+lines")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape to long format. Using readable columns names would help.

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  setNames(paste0('V', 1:7)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -V1)

p <- ggplot(df2, aes(V1, value, color = key)) + geom_line()
plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

[image]